# Ajax Response show different view

Tags: jquery, ajax

This is My Ajax Response

**`{"date1":"1","date2":"1","date3":"1","date4":"1","date5":"1","date6":"1","date7":"0"}`**

```
$("#mycalender .span").html(data.days);
```

I want to show like this **`M T W T F S S`**

if value is 1 then i want to add one class

Comment: Can you  explain more?

Comment: for display insted of date1 i want M and if date1:1 then i want to 1 class else 0 i want to another class